# Will this switch work for a lamp?

Tags: switch, lamp

I'm building a custom desk lamp and was thinking of doing something "different" or "fun" for the switch.  The lamp will look something like this with a few tweaks.

[image]

The lamp will be used in the US.  Will this switch work?  If not, is there an alternative?

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B005TX3OEC/ref=s9_simh_gw_p60_d0_i2?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=06ZT7A1CPWT1V09TM7YN&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=1970559082&pf_rd_i=desktop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005TX3OEC)

Answer (score 1):

One of the Commenters says: "it's made to stick bare wire in hole then screw down to clamp wire in place. 18-22 guage wire is about the largest size you can fit."

18-22 Gauge is not rated for lighting circuits.

Also its Momentary, so you would need some Latching relay to keep the circuit on.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer...  Any ideas of a switch of similar style (push button) that I might be able to use in this project?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a momentary switch, this means that the light will only stay on when you press on it.

Also, this switch is rated for 12V, you will need a switch rated for your voltage along with the amps needed for the light in the lamp.

This one might fit your needs:
http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Lock-Stainless-Steel-Push-Button-OFF-ON-SPST-Switch-12v-110V-120v-10Amp-250v-5A-/291240585685?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43cf4aa9d5